# Is there a way to call a mySQL stored procedure from PHP while passing a $_SESSION variable as its parameter?

Tags: php, html, mysql

## What I'm trying to do:

- I need to call a stored procedure in PHP, **getStudentDevices()**, stored on a mySQL server.
- It takes one parameter, **@p0**.
- I want to supply that parameter using a $_SESSION variable, **studentID**.

## What works:

- I can call the stored procedure from phpMyAdmin and it provides the correct result. So its not an issue with the procedure.
- I can query the database from PHP using a *different* select statement, and I get the results displayed how I want, so I don't think there's an issue with connecting to the DB from PHP.

## What I've tried:

This is the PHP used to fetch the results and display them in a table using the same method as mentioned previously:
I have tried using {} to pass the $_SESSION variable too.

```
<?php
$sql = "CALL getStudentDevices(.$_SESSION["studentID"].)"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  // $conn details omitted

// If selection is not empty
// Create table row for each record selected
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table> <tr> <th>DeviceID</th> <th>DeviceName</th> </tr>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr> <td>".$row["DeviceID"]."</td> <td>".$row["DeviceName"]."</td> </tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     // If select is empty then
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Here is the stored procedure (which works perfectly when called from the DBMS):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`hostname` PROCEDURE `getStudentDevices`(IN `StudentID` VARCHAR(11))
    READS SQL DATA
SELECT Devices.DeviceID, Devices.DeviceName FROM Accounts
    LEFT JOIN Courses ON Accounts.CourseID = Courses.CourseID
    LEFT JOIN Course_Category cc ON Courses.CourseID = cc.CourseID
    LEFT JOIN Categories ON cc.Category = Categories.Category
    LEFT JOIN Devices ON Categories.Category = Devices.Category
    WHERE Accounts.StudentID = @p0 AND Devices.Available = 1$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[The table creation method works when using a select statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ijk2.png) ,however, when I try to open this page using the stored procedure, nothing is displayed. The entire page is blank. Please note that security is not a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you build your query, you are mixing up the string building styles.
And you are missing quotes for the parameter

The old school style:

```
$sql = 'CALL getStudentDevices("' . $_SESSION["studentID"] . '")';
```

Variable passing:

```
$sql = "CALL getStudentDevices(\"{$_SESSION["studentID"]}\")";
```